# Represent a relationship

Tags: database, relational-database, erd

I've currently come to a complete halt in thinking.

I have a table called Account, which has attributes accountID(PK), firstName,lastName etc... and I have made a table called Class which has attributes classID(PK), className, classTime etc... Many to many relationship exists between the 2 tables.

I need to break the many to many relationship. The conditions are: after an account is made, it may be enrolled to a class as either student or instructor but not both. However, an account could have an instructor role in one class, and a student role in another class

So I thought of making a table called Enrollment, and having accountID, classID and enrollment type, but what I'm uncertain on is the relationships needed btwn Account and Enrollment and Enrollment and Class. Would it be one account to many enrollment?

If anyone would be kind enough to help me understand this I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your design seems correct.

In this model, an account has many enrollments; and enrollment has exactly one account.

A class has many enrollments; an enrollment has exactly one class.

If you add a unique key to the enrollment with account_id, class_id, you fulfill the rule that an account may have only one enrollment for a given class.

Comment: Just on the second point.... ''A class has many enrollments; an enrollment has exactly one account''. So would that be a one to many from class to enrollment, meaning  a class has many enrollments, but an enrollment has one class?